# Changing the timezone and timestamp of mysql server

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to change the current timezone to Asia/Calcutta by using the following query in phpmyadmin. But its not working

```
     SET `time_zone` = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

My Current TIMESTAMP shows
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
            2014-03-13 22:23:13

When i run this query
         SET `time_zone` = 'Asia/Calcutta'

I'm Getting this error
         #1298 - Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Calcutta'

Is there any other way to change the timezone?

Answer (score 7):

Try this it works for me just run this command in phpmyadmin 
SET time_zone = "+05:30";

Answer (score 2):

set time_zone = '+5:30'  this is correct method. using sql query.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SET `time_zone` = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

**IN PHP**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
```

Comment: if the mysql documentation was any good why would people ask such stupid questions in SO

Answer (score 1):

The Asia/Calcutta time zone has been deemed obsolete and replaced by Asia/Kolkata.

Comment: 'Asia/Calcutta' is correct.[PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones
search "Asia/Calcutta" and you will see it

Comment: MariaDB [(none)]> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata';
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Asia/Kolkata'

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code to top of your php.ini file

```
date.timezone = "Asia/Calcutta"
```

[Reference](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/setting-the-timezone-for-php-in-the-phpini-file)

---

Another way without doing change in php.ini directly change in your php file where your code is execute.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();

echo date("Y-m-d h:iA", starttotime($whateverdate) );
?>
```

Comment: I have php5.ini file and added this line in that too.

Comment: Try this without ; in the begining.

Comment: Tried... Do i need to restart the server??

Comment: Its a shared hosting server...i cant restart

Comment: ok then create same php.ini and add it in your root directory. it will overwrite main php.ini

Comment: Den wat about php5.ini file?

Comment: simply create custom php5.ini file with adding above code and put in your root directory and test it

Comment: sorry try with php.ini file not php5.ini

Comment: Dude, date_default_timezone_set function will change the server time in mysql? I already have so many records in my tables, now i want to get exact date records but i'm getting yesterday records also due to timezone issue

Comment: no it will not change  from server + mysql but yes it will convert timeinto indian timezone from current project.

Comment: I want to retrieve records from mysql tables according to our timeszones. i already used date_default_timezone_set in my root index.php page to convert all the times. and yes all the data stored in correct timezone but my server timezone is different than my local apache server. i have changed the timezone in phpmyadmin my localserver but its the same query in my hosting server